# Excel VBA - How to program Range object to move horizontally?

Tags: excel, vba

I know if move vertically with "Range object", for example A1, A2, A3... i could use code like Range("A" & i), and just change the "i" value. However, if to move horizontally like A1, B1, C1... is there a similar way to do that with Range object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Cells` object. This works using a row and column number, so `Cell(1,1)` is A1, `Cells(1,2)` is B1, `Cells(2,2)` is B2, etc. You can create a range of cells using `Range(Cells(1,1),Cells(2,2))` which is A1:B2. You can combine the two, although I generally don't: `Range("A1", Cells(2, 2))`.

If referencing a range object also ensure you're explicit about the worksheet. If Sheet1 is the activesheet then `Range("A1", Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 2))` will throw an error as it's trying to create a range out of A1 on Sheet1 and B2 on Sheet2.

Comment: Do you know why if i use Cells object, for example type "Cells(1,1)." and there is no autocompletion. i.e. automatically shows property, methods etc... like when i type "Range("A1").""? Do i have to wrape it like "Range(Cells(1,1))." to get the autocompletion?

Comment: Sorry, no idea why there's no autocomplete - I'm having the same problem with `FIND` at the moment.  But if I type `Cells(` then it pops up the `_Default([RowIndex],[ColumnIndex])` message.

Comment: For some reason the `Item` property of `Cells` doesn't return a typed `Range` object, which is why you don't get Intellisense.

Comment: @RealLifePM... the intelisense (autocomplete) for `Cells()` is pretty much the same as for `Range()`.

Answer (score 0):

`Cells` is generally the most straightforward (and easiest) way to do it, re: Darren's answer.

Though it is possible to create work-arounds so that the `Range` method may also be used. There are several possibilities, but the easiest of them is probably [Range().Offset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060.aspx).

> *expression* .Offset(RowOffset, ColumnOffset)

The latter argument is what we're interested in, but it's useful to learn how the entire method works.

Example usage:
`Range("A1").Offset(1, 0)` is equal to `Range("A2")` (One row down from `A1`)
`Range("A1").Offset(0, 1)` is equal to `Range("B1")` (One column to the right from `A1`)
`Range("C1").Offset(1, 1)` is equal to `Range("D2")` (One row down, one column to the right, from `C1`)
`Range("C1").Offset(0, 3)` is equal to `Range("F1")` (Three columns to the right from `C1`)

(You'll notice `Range().Offset` uses the same syntax regarding row/columns as `Cells`.)

You can also do it in a more roundabout way:

```
Sub arrayTest()
    Dim letterArray() As String
    Dim rng As Range

    ' Declare a bunch of letters here - expand if you need more columns
    ' Using a 1 as the first letter because remembering Option Base 1 is not something I prefer
    ' but you may of course do it. In that case, remove the "1:" from the beginning of the string
    Const letterString As String = "1:a:b:c:d:e:f:g:h:i:j:k:l:m:n:o:p:q:r:s:t:u:v:w:x:y:z"

    ' Fill an array with our letters
    letterArray() = Split(letterString, ":")

    ' Range("A1")
    Set rng = Range(letterArray(1) & "1")
    Debug.Print rng.Address

    ' Range("B2")
    Set rng = Range(letterArray(2) & "2")
    Debug.Print rng.Address

    ' Range("M83")
    Set rng = Range(letterArray(13) & "83")
    Debug.Print rng.Address

    Debug.Print vbCr
    ' Or we can loop it
    For i = 1 To UBound(letterArray)
        Debug.Print Range(letterArray(i) & "1").Address
    Next i
End Sub
```

> $A$1
>   $B$2
>   $M$83

Print-out from the loop is omitted because it takes up a lot of space... but run the macro in the VBE and view the result in the Immediate Window (Ctrl+G).

Comment: Thanks a lot, Vegard.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub MoveRange_by_NumberOfColumn(rn As Range, NCol As Integer)

    rn.Cut Cells(rn.Row, rn.Column + NCol)

End Sub


Sub Test_MoveRange_by_NumberOfColumn()

    Dim rn As Range
    Set rn = Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
    MoveRange_by_NumberOfColumn rn, 3

End Sub
```